# regex to find a particular pattern in a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find a particular pattern in a string and extract a substring out of it. 
Eg of the String:

```
{'Opening Cost P&L per store','Opening Costs Capital per store','Average Monthly Revenue','GROSS MARGIN %'}] = N:DB('Store Cost', 
    !Country and Region, DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, 
    !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Retailer Type'), ATTRS('New Stores', 
    !New Stores, '}Map_}Link_New Store Plan_3CStore Cost'), DB('New Store Plan', 
    !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Size'), 
    DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 
    'Franchise/Corporate'), 'DATA')
```

I have to search for:
`DB('`    only, not other pattern like   `S:DB('`   or    `DB('}`.

Then after finding this pattern I have to take text in list which is available after this pattern and in quotes only
e.g.

```
DB('Metrics cube-HumanResource',    !country, !Time, !gometric, !Metric Indicators), CONTINUE)​
DB('Metrics cube-InternalProcess',     !country, 'Total of Product', !Time, !gometric, !Metric Indicators), CONTINUE);​
```

then output will be:

```
1 - Metrics cube-HumanResource
2 - Metrics cube-InternalProcess​
```

This is my code. But its not printing anything:

```
public class StringRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{'Opening Cost P&L per store','Opening Costs Capital per store','Average Monthly Revenue','GROSS MARGIN %'}] = N:DB('Store Cost', \n" +
                "    !Country and Region, DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, \n" +
                "    !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Retailer Type'), ATTRS('New Stores', \n" +
                "    !New Stores, '}Map_}Link_New Store Plan_3CStore Cost'), DB('New Store Plan', \n" +
                "    !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Size'), \n" +
                "    DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, \n" +
                "    'Franchise/Corporate'), 'DATA')";
        String[] strArray = str.split(",");
        for(String s : strArray){
            if(s.matches("DB\\('.+'")){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you have until now?

Comment: I tried splitting the paragraph with `,`. But not able to search each string with that particular pattern.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ and finally, show these in the question, not in the comments

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` instead of splitting the `String`. You will get a result easier. Using the following regex :

```
.*?[^:]DB\((.*?)\).*?
```

This will capture the content of every DB(.*) not precede with a `:`. Using lazy quantifier `*?` will prevent problem like capturing more than just the text until the closing parenthesis.

From [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JuisBp/1):

```
    String regex = ".*?[^:]DB\\((.*?)\\).*?";
    String string = "{'Opening Cost P&L per store','Opening Costs Capital per store','Average Monthly Revenue','GROSS MARGIN %'}] = N:DB('Store Cost', \n"
            + "    !Country and Region, DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, \n"
            + "    !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Retailer Type'), ATTRS('New Stores', \n"
            + "    !New Stores, '}Map_}Link_New Store Plan_3CStore Cost'), DB('New Store Plan', \n"
            + "    !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Size'), \n"
            + "    DB('New Store Plan', !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, \n" + "    'Franchise/Corporate'), 'DATA')";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("> " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Results :

```
> 'New Store Plan', !Country and Region, 
    !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Retailer Type'  
> 'New Store Plan', 
    !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 'Size'  
> 'New Store Plan', !Country and Region, !ID numbers, !Budget version, 
    'Franchise/Corporate'
```

Comment: Spot on! Worked like charm

Comment: `Pattern` `Matcher` just made it a lot simple. Never thought of this.

Comment: @XoXo Remember, to extract or replace value with a specific "pattern" (**(DB(...)**), `Pattern` is usually a better approch than splitting ;)